# What happens when min.compaction.lag.ms is greater than log.cleaner.max.compaction.lag.ms?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-topic, kafka-cluster

I'm using Kafka 2.2.0, so the option to configure `max.compaction.lag.ms` per topic is not yet available.

Globally I have `log.cleaner.max.compaction.lag.ms=86400000` (one day):

For the topic `__consumer_offsets`, I'd like to delay the compaction to at least three days, to keep some short-term history.

I could set `min.compaction.lag.ms` to `259200000` (three days), but it seems contrary to the smaller `log.cleaner.max.compaction.lag.ms`. What would happen if I did so nonetheless?

Answer (score 1):

The compaction will be performed if either happens:

1. Both conditions for dirty/clean ratio and `min.compaction.lag` are fulfilled

or

2. `max.compaction.lag` is fulfilled

So it is OK to have `min.compaction.lag.ms` bigger than `max.compaction.lag.ms`.
Since they are used in 2 different conditions and do not contradict each other.

BTW, what did you choose in the end? What were your results?

Comment: "So it is OK to have `min.compaction.lag.ms` less than `max.compaction.lag.ms`. -> Sure, but I was talking about the other way around, i.e., "max less than min".

Comment: "what did you choose in the end? What were your results?" -> Nothing. I simply did not increase `min.compaction.lag.ms` for `__consumer_offsets` and abandoned the idea of having some short-term history for that topic. :-)

Comment: @TobiasHermann Sorry, I've updated the answer based on your comment